# Authorization Denied using PHP cURL functions according to REST API specification

Tags: rest, php-curl, api-key

Am trying to connect to a REST API using PHP's cURL functions and getting an Authorization Denied message. My first time consuming a REST API and using cURL to do so, so need to make sure I'm not doing anything obviously wrong. This is necessary function of a billing/payroll/verification program  that collects data which verifies staff providing services then sends the necessary verification data using the POST method according to the REST API specs. A lot of time wrapped into it so any comments greatly appreciated. The manual mentions:

```
"security": [{
"api_key": [] 
 }
 ]
```

The REST API 3.0 in the manual specifies the following regarding security: :

```
"headers": {},
"securitySchemes": {
"api_key": {
"type": "apiKey",
"name": "api_key",
"in": "header"}
}
```

Here's the PHP cURL script I'm using:

```
$post_data = json_encode($objTemplate);
$crl = curl_init('https://api.someapitestsite.io/submitter/06700809/');
curl_setopt($crl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($crl, CURLINFO_HEADER_OUT, true);
curl_setopt($crl, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($crl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post_data); 
curl_setopt($crl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
'Content-Type: application/json',
'type : apiKey',
'name : api_key',
'api_key: [-api--key--goes--here-]' ) );
curl_setopt($crl, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);
$result = curl_exec($crl);
$result = curl_exec($ch);
if ($result == false)
    echo $crl;
curl_close($ch);  
echo($result);
```

Here is the header returned Authorization Denied message:

HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden
Server: nginx
Date: Tue, 14 Feb 2023 16:17:04 GMT
Content-Type: application/json
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Connection: keep-alive
Response-Token: 51b9e9c4-eb6f-46c7-9294-2a75a84eebe2
Vary: Origin
Vary: Origin
Vary: Access-Control-Request-Method
Vary: Access-Control-Request-Headers
X-Ratelimit-Limit: -1
X-Ratelimit-Remaining: 0
X-Ratelimit-Reset: 0
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
X-Xss-Protection: 1; mode=block
Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=31536000; includeSubdomains
X-Frame-Options: sameorigin
Content-Security-Policy: default-src 'self'
data: https://styles.transcend.csra.io ; script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval'; img-src 'self'
data: https://styles.transcend.csra.io https://images.unsplash.com/ https://source.unsplash.com/; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' https://styles.transcend.csra.io https://fonts.googleapis.com/; font-src 'self' https://fonts.googleapis.com/ https://fonts.gstatic.com; connect-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' https://api.someapitestsite.io/; frame-ancestors 'self';
{"errors":[{"errorCode":"4070","errorMessage":"Authorization denied. Please contact  Operations Support."}]}

Have tried a few variations of the CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER above.
Using these apiKey variations also gives Authorization denied:

```
'security'=>'api_key: [-api--key--goes--here-]',
'Authorization'=>'api_key: [-api--key--goes--here-]'
```

and any variation without  'api_key: [-api--key--here-]' gets an authorization missing message such as using

```
'Authorization' =>  'basic [-api--key--here-]'
```

or

```
'api_key = [-api--key--here-]'
```

Comment: Do the API docs say to send JSON-encoded instead of POST's normal url-encoded format?

Comment: yes JSON encoded data is specified